# Font Awesome icon cut off in Chrome when using the btn-small bootstrap class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, font-size, font-awesome

Has anyone else run into this before? I created a very simple example on jsfiddle to reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/3UHSc/2/

```
<a class="btn btn-small">
    <i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit
</a>
```

The button looks fine in Firefox and IE, but in Chrome the top pixel of the icon is cut off. I am able to work around it by adding a style rule to make the icon font smaller:

```
.btn-small > i
{
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

But am wondering if there is a better / cleaner way to get this working.

Comment: Been a long time now, but I've just had the same issue. Seems to be a [common issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/353)

Comment: Me too. It isn't noticeable with some of the icons, but others, like `icon-print` get cut off in `.btn-small` (at 11.9px).

Comment: i found that the icon gets cut off in font sizes between 11.5px and 11.99px. in 11.49px px it's fine. not sure whether it's a kerning issue or somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

SVG icon fonts have rendering issues in Chrome. Try swapping the woff file with the SVG file in your source. I wrote a blog post about [preventing icon font cutoff in Chrome](http://john-dugan.com/prevent-icon-font-cut-off-chrome/) too that you can check out.

ie change this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

to this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    /*
        The SVG font has rendering problems in Chrome on Windows.
        To fix this, I have moved the SVG font above the woff font
        so that the woff file gets downloaded.
    */
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can overwrite the CSS and add a non-breaking space (`\00a0`) and adjust the extra left space with CSS. Example:

```
.fa-check-square-o:before {
    content: "\00a0\f046";
}
```